# AWS RDS POSTGRES - Japanese/Chinese Full Text Search support

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, full-text-search

I have a requirement to support FTS (Full Text Search) of Japanese and Chinese on PostgreSQL.

I am aware that there are extensions to handle this however AWS RDS PostgreSQL appears to restrict the available extensions to a certain list.

Would anyone be able to suggest strategies to enable FTS for Japanese and Chinese given the restrictions RDS imposes (or be able to correct any miscomprehension's I may hold)?

EDIT: We're on 9.6.5 and the available extensions can be found at:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Extensions.96x

Comment: Do you have sources of what extensions AWS RDS PostgreSQL supports? Could you add that list of restricted extensions to your [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/193019/edit)?

Comment: Unfortunately, we can't break the RDS's extension restriction. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Extensions
     These are extentions supported by RDS.